# Evenly Spaced Nav with Foundation 4 - Broken in Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox, css-float, zurb-foundation

I'm using Foundation 4's built-in Navigation component and I'm using the table/table-cell css trick to evenly space the horizontal elements and style it. However I've hit a wall with Firefox. The following example works exactly how I want in every browser except Firefox and I can't for the life of me figure it out.

I've uploaded the example to my server: [See Live Example Here](http://www.liquidvisual.net/files/stackoverflow/build/index.html)

This is the example in Safari:

[image: Working in Safari Screen]

And this is the same in Firefox:

[image]

Any help you could give me I would REALLY appreciate it!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

make changes in these css to fix it in firefox i tested only in firefox

```
*, *:before, *:after {
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
vertical-align: middle;
```

}

```
.top-bar .dropdown {
background: none no-repeat scroll 0 0 #8D8C8C;
text-align: center;
width: 17.2%;
```

}

```
.top-bar-section .dropdown li {
height: auto;
width: 100%;
```

}

```
.top-bar-section ul {
display: inline;
height: auto !important;
width: 100%;
```

}

```
.top-bar-section .dropdown {
left: 0;
top: auto;
```

}

Comment: Thanks for your message but unfortunately it's still not working for me. It's fixed the height of the bar, but the dropdown functionality is still broken on hover.